# How to easily play around with the classes in an Scala/SBT project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to Scala/SBT and I'm having trouble understanding how to just try out the classes and functions of a package to see what they're about, to get a feel for them.  For example, take https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/rtree2d .  What I want to do is something like (in the top level folder of the project)

```
   # sbt
   > console
   > import com.github.plokhotnyuk.rtree2d.core._ 
     ...
```

etc.  But this won't work as it can't find the import even though this is in the project.  I apologize for the vague question, though I hope from my hand-waving it's clear what I want to do.  Another way to put it maybe, is that I'm looking for something like the intuitive ease of use which I've come to take for granted in Python -- using just bash and the interpreter.  As a last resort I can create a separate project and import this package and write a `Main` object but this seems much too roundabout and cumbersome for what I want to do.  I'd also like if possible to avoid IDEs, since I never really feel in control with them as they do all sorts of things behind the scenes in the background adding a lot of bulk and complexity.

Comment: Try `rtree2d-coreJVM/console`.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Just to be clear that's `cd rtree2d-core/jvm` then `sbt console`

Comment: I was suggesting `sbt 'rtree2d-coreJVM/console'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rtree2d` takes advantage of sbt's multi-module capabilities; a common use for this is to put the core functionality in a module and have less core aspects (e.g. higher-level APIs or integrations with other projects) in modules which depend on the core: all of these modules can be published independently and have their own dependencies.

This can be seen in the `build.sbt` file:

```
// The main project -- LR
lazy val rtree2d = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(`rtree2d-coreJVM`, `rtree2d-coreJS`, `rtree2d-benchmark`)
  // details omitted --LR

// Defines the basic skeleton for the core JVM and JS projects --LR
lazy val `rtree2d-core` = crossProject(JVMPlatform, JSPlatform)
  // details omitted

// Turns the skeleton into the core JVM project --LR
lazy val `rtree2d-coreJVM` = `rtree2d-core`.jvm

// Turns the skeleton into the core JS project --LR
lazy val `rtree2d-coreJS` = `rtree2d-core`.js

lazy val `rtree2d-benchmark` = project
```

In sbt, commands can be scoped to particular modules with `module/command`, so in the interactive sbt shell (from the top-level), you can do

```
> rtree2d-coreJVM/console
```

to run the console within the JVM core module.  You could also run `sbt 'rtree2d-coreJVM/console'` directly from the shell in the top level, though this may require some care around shell quoting etc.